# error: request for member ‘txt’ in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, function, file, if-statement, while-loop

Excuse me, I have a problem in my code when I try to compile it, and I don't understand what's the error to solve:

**"6:26:error:requestformember‘txt’in something not a structure or
union"**

```
                fichero = fopen(fichero.txt,"r");
```

Can anyone help me please

I leave you my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int calcular(char nombre[]){
  FILE *fichero; int contar, maximo = 0;
  char caracter;
  fichero = fopen(fichero.txt,"r");
        if(fichero == NULL)
         printf("ERROR de Apertura");
        else{
             while(!feof(fichero)){
                 fscanf(fichero, "%c", & caracter);
                 if(caracter == '/n'){
                   if(contar > maximo)
                      maximo = contar;
                      contar = 0;
                      fclose(fichero);        
                      fclose(salida);
                 }
             }
             contar++;
        }
        return(linea);
}
```

Comment: I suspect, that `fichero.txt` is a filename. Thus, you must write it as a string literal with enclosing double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use double quotes for `fichero.txt` to be a string `"fichero.txt"`. As it is the compiler is considering it the `FILE *` object you declared earlier so it's complaining because

1. It's a pointer, so accessing it's members should be done with the `->` operator.
2. It has no member `txt` of course.

Comment: also I forgot to comment another trouble I have , and which I don't know if any of you have noticed, and is that the "linea" and "salida" variables are not declared because I don't know in which part of the code they  go

Comment: @V_WraMphT3R I am very busy. But feel free to mail me to iharob@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the string literal fichero.txt to fopen() without double quotes, tricking the compiler into thinking that fichero is a struct and that txt is a member of that struct.

Try:

```
fopen("fichero.txt", "r");
```

Comment: Yes and there is a `FILE *fichero;` Mixed with other declarations, which is why declaring multiple variables in a single line is bad. Worse declaring variables with different types in the same line.

Comment: ok thanks, also I forgot to comment another trouble I have , and which I don't know if any of you have noticed, and is that the "linea" and "salida" variables are not declared because I don't know in which part of the code they  go

Comment: It really depends on where you intend to use them. If you only want to access those values within the calcular() function then declaring them local to that function should be sufficient. You've already made declarations locally within that function so making subsequent delcarations shouldn't be too tough to figure out.

Comment: To declared them in the function, like you said, I get this in the terminal:                                 fichero.c: In function ‘calcular’:
fichero.c:8:7: error: conflicting types for ‘fichero’
   int fichero;fichero.c:4:9: note: previous declaration of ‘fichero’ was here
   FILE *fichero;
fichero.c:10:11: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
   fichero = fopen("fichero.txt","r");

Comment: Well, as iharob already pointed out you have a FILE * already named fichero...you can't have two declarations using the same name local to teh same function. Either change the name of the FILE * or choose a different name for subsequent declarations.

Comment: wait, I lacked more, forgive:

Comment: fichero.c:11:20: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
         if(fichero == NULL)
                    
fichero.c:14:26: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘feof’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
              while(!feof(fichero)){
In file included from fichero.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:828:12: note: expected ‘struct FILE *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
extern int feof (FILE *__stream) __THROW __wur;              fichero.c:15:25: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fscanf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast   fscanf(fichero,"%c",& caracter);

Comment: In file included from /usr/include/features.h:364:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:27,
                 from fichero.c:1:
/usr/include/stdio.h:443:12: note: expected ‘struct FILE * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 extern int __REDIRECT (fscanf, (FILE *__restrict __stream,
            ^

Comment: fichero.c:20:30: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fclose’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
                       fclose(fichero);
                              ^
In file included from fichero.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:237:12: note: expected ‘struct FILE *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 extern int fclose (FILE *__stream);
            ^
fichero.c:21:30: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fclose’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
                       fclose(salida);

Comment: In file included from fichero.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:237:12: note: expected ‘struct FILE *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 extern int fclose (FILE *__stream);
            ^
fichero.c:26:16: error: ‘linea’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         return(linea);
                ^
fichero.c:26:16: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in

Comment: Mate...I try my best not to be short with people, and don't want to come across as rude or condescending. You really need to get back to basics. I think that for every question that is answered you'll come back with 2 or 3 more, people will help you but they won't instruct or teach you the fundamentals. You need to do some reading and figure out the basics.